# Mails sometimes duplicated when recieved in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, email, imap

On one of my Mac computers, when I receive an email that gets moved to another folder with Mail.app's filtering rules, sometimes I end up with two copies on the email: one in the intended folder, and another remaining in the root inbox.

- It started last year with Ventura, but still happens with Sonoma.
- It happens only on one of my Macs, never with the others, the filtering rules being identical on all machines.
- It happens infrequently, not with every email.
- The mail box is standard IMAP (not GMail).
- Rebulding folders had no effect on this bug.

I haven't been able to solve this problem so far, so any insight would be welcome.